# In Terraform, how do you output a list from an array of objects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I'm creating a series of s3 buckets with this definition:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "map" {
  for_each = local.bucket_settings
  bucket = each.key
...
}
```

I'd like to output a list of the website endpoints:

```
 output "website_endpoints" {
    # value = aws_s3_bucket.map["example.com"].website_endpoint
    value = ["${keys(aws_s3_bucket.map)}"] 
 }
```

What's the syntax to pull out a list of the endpoints (rather than the full object properties)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you just want to get a `list` of `website_endpoint`, then you can do:

```
 output "website_endpoints" {
    value = values(aws_s3_bucket.map)[*].website_endpoint
 }
```

This uses [splat](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions/splat.html) expression.

Answer (score 6):

You can loop over your buckets  with for loop and output specific attribute, in this case website_endpoint.

```
output "endpoint" {
    value = [for s in aws_s3_bucket.map : s.website_endpoint[*]]
}
```